# Minimum distance between convex polygon vertices on a plane?

Tags: geometry, polygons

I'm facing the following problem: I have a plane with a set of simple convex polygons on top of it. I'm required to prove that however I pick two vertices, one as a starting point and one as a target, the minimum distance between them will consist of straight line segments, each of which joining two vertices. The following image will illustrate the idea (shortest path from S to G in red).

[image: Example. The red path is the shortest from S to G]

I'm struggling to figure out how to start proving that this is the case. Please no complete proof since that's my task, I appreciate any hint to the right direction.

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention that the path can't cut a polygon, as in no point of the path can be inside any of them.

Comment: Maybe using geodesic distance and its propagation mode... as described for example [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00528999/document)

Comment: @JeanMarie: Thanks for sharing. I took an Artificial intelligence class but it didn't include computer vision so I'm not familiar enough with it to use it as a tool to prove an assertion. However I'm well willing to check out the article you linked, could you please indicate a specific section or chapter describing the relevant part for my application? Appreciated!

Comment: See Fig. 3.29 page 100 of the document and the text surrounding it.

Comment: The key notion is the visibility graph which is explained (a little) in this [slideshow](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/old/_media/courses/a4m36pah/lecture01.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie: Thanks, I didn't find what I was looking for directly in the documents you linked but I managed to find it elsewhere: https://cs.smith.edu/~istreinu/Teaching/Courses/274/Spring98/Projects/Philip/fp/visibility.htm

Comment: Good catch: Indeed, it looks a very complete set of information about this issue. !

Comment: I am not sure that the way the problem is stated the solution requires that there are more than one segment - consider the two close vertices - no segment is involved for the shortest distance.